# Is it possible for Lombok project to return an interface of an object?

Tags: java, annotations, getter, lombok

Java [Lombok Project](http://projectlombok.org/) is just an awesome stuff. It provides a possibility to get rid of tons of generated getters / setters and use simple, comprehensible annotations.

But for my automation project I should return interface of some element. Is it possible for lombok to return interface of an object?

For example, I have:

```
private ButtonElement button = new ButtonElement(....);
public IElement getButton() {
     return button;
}
```

and would like to have something like:

```
@Getter   // with with IElement return type?   
private ButtonElement button = new ButtonElement(....);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it's clumsy:

```
@Getter
private IElement button = new ButtonElement(....);
```

But that will of course make it harder to access some methods of `ButtonElement`. So you may want to use either:

```
private _button = new ButtonElement(....);
@Getter
private IElement button = _button;
```

i.e. you need two fields, one with the interface and one with the real type.

or

```
@Getter
private IElement button = new ButtonElement(....);
private ButtonElement button() { return (ButtonElement) button; }
```

i.e. you now have an internal getter which casts and returns the real type.

Note that Java allows you to define a method which expands the type. So if you have an `interface` which says:

```
IElement getButton();
```

you can implement this with

```
public ButtonElement getButton() {...}
```

Not only will this work but if Java knows which `getButton()` you're calling, it will happily give you a `ButtonElement`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the field type as the interface, it will of course return the interface, otherwise, I think there's no way.

I would simply change your code to

```
@Getter      
private IElement button = new ButtonElement(....);
```